# Why is my heap usage so high in the editor and how do I reduce it?

Tags: anylogic

I am working on a model and have been having consistent issues with heap size/usage. I already updated the config.ini file to expand the heap size up to 4GB, however that entire heap is being consumed constantly by the AnyLogic editor environment. The screenshots below show (1) my visualvm profiler showing heap usage in the editor (the other 2 processes listed use less than about 300MB combined), (2) a screenshot of the memory sampler in visualvm, and (3) a screenshot from my AnyLogic IDE showing the utilized heap. When I hit the garbage collector icon in the IDE, it barely moves the needle.

This is a decently large model, however I have developed much larger, more computationally expensive models and have never had this issue before. It makes the development process *extremely* slow, as any time I click a logic block or edit any property within a block it takes several seconds to load/buffer.

Looking at the memory sampler hasn't helped me track down the issue and I can't find anything definitively points to the problem in my model, but I don't understand why I would have 700MB of local variable storage (I have worked with models with 2-3x more variables than this model), and I have no clue what `byte[]` or `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.AnnotatableInfo` would represent in my model.

How should I go about reducing/optimizing my heap usage?? Any help or pointers you can provide are very much appreciated!!

[image: Pic of typical heap usage in editor]

[image: visualVM profiler of editor running]

[image: visualVM memory sampler]

Comment: Is this an issue at runtime or design time (i.e. in the IDE)? Also, you sure you sampling the right item in VisualVM? You need to look at the `com.anylogic.ms.MS`, no?

Comment: Also, what AL version? Does it work better with those larger models on the same machine with the same AL version? In other words: are you 100% sure it is the _model_, not something else?

Comment: The issue is at design time (in the IDE) and I am using AL Professional 8.8.4. I looked at com.anylogic.ms.MS but the heap usage for that pid is less than 500 MB at most - usually around 200 MB. The process shown in the screenshots is definitely the primary consumer of heap memory. If I close this model and open up similar size or larger models I do not have this issue, so it certainly seems to be something with this model alone.

Comment: Hi Max, could you share some info about your model structure? i had something similar where ive tried to model the layout of the shop using a lot of curves. Changing from curves to straight lines made it a bit better.